# Loop for ascii arts in C

Tags: c, loops, ascii-art

I have to create loops that shows some ascci arts in C. I made the
first one, and it is working fine. But I can't do the second. I tried
with strings, loops, but I can't think in a right logic. When I
thought that I got it, the program not worked. Can you help me?

This is the drawing that I need  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAQKg.jpg

If you can help with the others I will thank you too!
[https://imgur.com/a/TeFBzpf
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKNbS.jpg](https://imgur.com/a/TeFBzpf<https://imgur.com/a/HJdDGHe)

PS: The user choose the highest line of the drawing

This is my code https://pastebin.com/y2Bx0aUc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int desenho;
  int tamanho;
  int original;
  char vamo[100];
  char teste[1];
  int i;
  int adicionar;
  int variavel;
   printf("Digite o desenho que quer (entre 1 e 5): \n");
   scanf("%d",&desenho);
   printf("Agora digite o tamanho da primeira linha: \n");
   scanf("%d",&tamanho);
   switch (desenho) {
     case 1:
     for (tamanho = tamanho; tamanho > 0; tamanho--){
       for (i = tamanho; i >0; i--){
         printf("*");
       }
       printf("\n");

     }
     break;
     case 2:
     original = tamanho;
     for (tamanho = tamanho; tamanho > 0; tamanho--){
       for (i = tamanho; i >0; i--){
         printf("*");
       }
       printf("\n");

     }
     printf("*\n");
      teste[0] = '*';
     for (adicionar = 0; adicionar < 100; adicionar++){
         vamo[adicionar] = teste[0];
         teste[0] = teste[0] + '*';

     }
     adicionar = 0;
     for (i = 0 ; i < original; i++){
       printf("%c", vamo[adicionar]);
       adicionar++;
     }


     break;
     case 3:

   return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: [why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_line(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_ascii(int height) {
    for (int i = height; i > 0; --i) {
        print_line(i);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i) {
        print_line(i);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    print_ascii(5);
}
```

The `print_ascii` function takes a single parameter which is the height of the pattern. At every height *i* we print a line containing *i* number of '*' characters.